# Array not getting sorted

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nsdate

I have an `array` of `structs`. In the `struct` I have two `NSDate` objects: `textLabel` and `detailTextlabel`. I'm trying to sort `textlabel` from  newest to oldest date/time. And I want `detailTextLabel` to also get ordered based on `textLabel`. And I want to do vice versa. Here's my code:

```
struct Item {
    let textLabel : NSDate
    let detailTextLabel : NSDate
}

var myItem = [Item]()

myItem.insert(Item(textLabel: myDateSecond, detailTextLabel: anotherDateSecond), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(textLabel: myDateThird, detailTextLabel: anotherDateThird), atIndex: 0)
myItem.insert(Item(textLabel: myDateFirst, detailTextLabel: anotherDateFirst), atIndex: 0)

@IBAction func sortButtonsAction(sender: UIButton) 
{
    if sender == firstBtn {
        myItem.sort({$0.textLabel.compare($1.detailTextLabel) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending})
    } else if sender == secondBtn {
        myItem.sort({$0.detailTextLabel.compare($1.textLabel) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending})
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Here's what happens:**

When I select `firstBtn`, it gets sorted the way I'm expecting it to.  But when I press `secondBtn`, nothing happens.

**What I want to happen**

When `secondBtn` gets selected, I want the `array` to get sorted based on the `detailTextLabel` data. Why isn't that happening?

Comment: What's `historyData`?

Comment: It was supposed to be `myItem`. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, looks like you're not comparing detailText w/ detailText and text w/ text, but mixing them. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort it by the textLabel date:

```
myItem.sort{$0.textLabel.compare($1.textLabel) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
```

To sort it by the detailTextLabel date:

```
myItem.sort{$0.detailTextLabel.compare($1.detailTextLabel) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
```

You should choose better names for your vars. It is a date, not a label.